# exit execution path in C# asp.net

Tags: c#

In my ASP.Net C# application, when there is an `if` statement which is true, I want to exit that function and don't want that rest of the lines to be executed in that function.

How can I to do that?

Comment: if your function's return type is `void` then you should use `return;` to return from function inside `if` block

Comment: can you add some code? Also you can always throw exception, but it is not recommended practice to use exceptions to control the flow.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya I would post that as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void Foo()
{
   if (....)
   {
       //First line of code

       return;

       //Second line of code won't fire
   }
}
```